# Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-styles' in AngularJS with Yeoman generator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

My code was working previously before, but seems to have stopped working. I tried yo angular:route api but this error was returned:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-styles'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/chalk/index.js:2:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I have added all the dependencies required to my package file, update npm (which is now on 2.0.0alpha), all npm packages, and ran npm install. The site still works when I grunt serve.

Comment: do you have this `ng-app="ansi-styles"`?

Comment: ng-app currently is mainCtrl where all my application logic is controlled. I found the reason I got the error. I had to change the npm root folder and reinstalled my packages in the default folder and now it works.

Comment: then close this issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(The O.P.):*

I found the reason I got the error. I had to change the npm root folder and reinstalled my packages in the default folder and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Just needed to run `npm install` here. Was a fresh clone out of Git.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the module globally working for me.

```
npm install ansi-styles -g
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error **after updating to Node v20.10**:

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
> throw err;
> ^
> Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-styles' Require stack:
>
> - E:\website\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js
> - E:\website\node_modules\react-dev-utils\chalk.js
> - E:\website\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
>   at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
>   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
>   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
>   at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
>   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
>   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
>   at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
>   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>   'E:\website\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js',
>   'E:\website\node_modules\react-dev-utils\chalk.js',
>   'E:\website\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js' ] }

I found this [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13297#issuecomment-1397294297), tried a few of the suggestions and narrowed the solution down to this command:

```
npx nuxi upgrade --force
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.9.0"    <-- then you will see nuxt added to your package.json file
  }
```