# Angular 4 compile error

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I just used npm install bootstrap@next on my project and got the following compile error. I'm new to angular.

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: 
>   no such file or directory, open 'D:\
>   projects\board\node_modules\ansi-html\index.js'  @
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3:15-35  @
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200  @ multi
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./www/main.ts

when compiling with ng serve i get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-styles'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\ssarfraz\git projects\board\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\chalk\index.js:3:20)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
```

Comment: what do you mean by npm install bootstrap@next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `npm install --save bootstrap` or `npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0` instead. And don't forget to include Bootstrap to your `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "styles.css"
],
```

And for the error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-styles'

There is a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25884689/6053654

Comment: @z123, did you create the project via Angular CLI?

Comment: yea its in the directory but intellij is not showing me the files that have a . before them

Comment: @z123, if so, you can open a window with your project and show all hidden files (`.angular-cli.json` should be in the root of your project). Or alternatively you can configure your IDE to show hidden files

Comment: i added it to the .angular-cli.json file but when i run ng serve i get the following compile errror i mentioned above. Thanks for the Help btw.

Comment: @z123, this link should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222519/error-cannot-find-module-ansi-styles-in-angularjs-with-yeoman-generator

Comment: @z123, sometimes it's the best solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

remove all files from \node_modules.bin
and  run "npm install" command.